# Replacing colours of image through colour palette in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

Sometimes I want to test out new colours using online sources like https://coolors.co/palette/a41623-f85e00-ffb563-ffd29d-918450. Is there a way to quickly exchange the colours in my document? I already found swatches. But there you have to manually change each color individually. Is there such a feature like in Powerpoint where you simply click on the colour scheme and it changes **automatically** like this: [image]

Answer (score 3):

No, there are no automated colour themes like that in Inkscape. However you can kind of do something similar, not quite as automated though.

Assuming you have a bunch of elements of different colours, you can select one, right click it and do *Select > Same Fill/stroke* etc. Then you can change all the selected objects in one go.

An example

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I found that as well. But that still seems like a lot of manual work. I'm thinking about writing an extension for that.